# How to auto size rows in react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make cards in group of 3 in each row using react-bootstrap. I made it, however if one cards height is longer, space occurs and makes it ugly for whole row. See pics(I basically don't want the space that I circled. How can I achieve this?). Photo:
[image]

Code:
My card component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card, CardGroup, Col, Container, Row, Tab, ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function SoruKart(props) {
    return (<Col>
        <Card style={{ margin: 10 }}>
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{props.title}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                    {props.description}
                </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
            <Card.Footer>
                <small className="text-muted">{props.type}</small>
            </Card.Footer>
        </Card>
    </Col>
    )
}

export default SoruKart
```

and here is where I use the component:

```
<Row>
          <SoruKart title="title" description="descriptResponseForm component actually exists. The path seems to be correct. How should I fix it? Why is import error occuring?ResponseForm component actually exists. The path seems to be correct. How should I fix it? Why is import error occuring?ResponseForm component actually exists. The path seems to be correct. How should I fix it? Why is import error occuring?ion" type="Kolay" />
          <SoruKart title="title" description="description" type="Kolay" />
          <SoruKart title="title" description="description" type="Kolay" />
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <SoruKart title="title" description="description" type="Kolay" />
          <SoruKart title="title" description="description" type="Kolay" />
          <SoruKart title="title" description="description" type="Kolay" />
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <SoruKart title="title" description="description" type="Kolay" />
          <SoruKart title="title" description="description" type="Kolay" />
          <SoruKart title="title" description="description" type="Kolay" />
        </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out. Instead of using rows and columns, I wrapped it in a div with 'card-columns' and everything lined up perfectly.